# "Best" and most "comprehensive" frequency list of the Russian language

Tags: грамматика

I really like learning from lists—-it's efficient and effective in my opinion. I have recently finished going through Nicholas J., Brown's frequency list of the top 10,000 words in the Russian Language (took about 13 months). And i have decided that I would like to continue using a list. However, the question is: "which list?".

Of course I am aware that frequency is a foggy subject, and that beyond 10,000, the order of words no longer has meaning. Nonetheless, the fact that someone took a large sample size and then recorded the most common words still has value.

So, I am searching for a list that has the following features:

1. Largest sample size (it's obvious why this is important)
2. Has the "best" methodology for ordering words by frequency...
3. Is the most recent (compiled within the last century
4. is the longest (i.e., contains the most words

of course I doubt it will be possible to meet all of these requests, but give it a shot

Thanks ))

Comment: Would that work: http://ruscorpora.ru/corpora-freq.html ?

Answer (score 3):

[О. Н. Ляшевская, С. А. Шаров, Частотный словарь современного русского языка](http://dict.ruslang.ru/freq.php) — 50,000 words on the ground of 0,3 bln. words in [Russian National Corpus](http://www.ruscorpora.ru/en/index.html).